# Is there any way to check if an IP address is a real IP address or private IP address?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ipv6, ip-address

Is there any way to check if an IP address is a real IP address or private IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, private IP addresses *are* real IP addresses. I assume you mean which IP addresses can be routed on the public Internet vs. which IP addresses cannot.

Check to see if the IP address is in one of the ranges marked as `False` under `Global` in the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). If it is, it cannot be routed on the public Internet. Also, multicast addresses (`224.0.0.0/4`) cannot be routed on the public Internet.

You can do the same thing for IPv6 with the [IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml). The globally routable IPv6 addresses all fall in the `2000::/3` range, but there are address ranges within that which are not routable on the public Internet, and any multicast IPv6 address (`ff00::/8`) is not routable on the public Internet.

Comment: private IP addresses are real IP addresses ? How ?

Comment: IP doesn't have any inherent capability to detect which addresses are artificially set aside as private addresses. The private addresses were set aside by RFC 1918, and the Internet carriers block them with access lists. There is nothing about the private addresses which otherwise keeps them from doing anything that public IP addresses can do.

Comment: There is one exception 2001:db8::/32 should be used for documentation and must not be routed on the Internet.

Comment: Also: even addresses that are not from RFC1918 can be put behind a NAT router and made private. What is "private" is just a matter of perspective

Comment: @JensLink, there are more ranges than the Documentation range in the IPv6 Global address range that can't be routed on the Internet: `2001::/23` IETF Protocol Assignments, `2001::/32` TEREDO, and `2001:2::/48` Benchmarking.

Comment: Teredo addresses are routed on the Internet. That is how traffic finds it's way from a native IPv6 host to a teredo relay.

Comment: TEREDO is _not_ globally routable. TEREDO _can_ be routed, but not globally. TEREDO IPv6 packets are encapsulated inside IPv4 packets: "_Teredo IPv6 packets are transmitted as UDP packets [RFC768] within
IPv4 [RFC791]. The source and destination IP addresses and UDP ports take values that are specified in this section. Packets can come in
one of two formats, simple encapsulation and encapsulation with
origin indication._"